# kill not working in while loop

Tags: bash, awk, kill, lsof

I want to kill all processes given by lsof in a while loop.

this works fine:

```
lsof -i tcp | grep -v iceweasel | awk '{ print $2 }' | while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"

done;
```

this one does not:

```
lsof -i tcp | grep -v iceweasel | awk '{ print $2 }' | while read -r line
    do
        kill "$line"

    done;
```

The error generated by this last while is:

```
./kill.all.sh: line 6: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

any idea? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? `kill` sends SIGTERM to the process, and the process can do with this signal what it wants (it can even ignore it). If you want to terminate the process for sure, send SIGKILL: `kill -9 $pid`, or `kill -KILL $pid`

Comment: sorry, I forgot error msg:

Comment: ./kill.all.sh: line 6: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: Then use `-t` option for `lsof`. The output of `lsof -i tcp` contains the header, and you are passing `PID` string to `kill`. Or ignore the first line with `awk 'NR > 1 { print $2 }'`

Comment: I will suggest you to use `| xargs`  instead of a while loop

Comment: Could you provide output of  command " bash -x kill.all.sh "

Comment: As @RuslanOsmanov said, the problem is the lsof header. By just modifing the awk command the problem is solved. However, I still suggest to use xargs instead of a while loop (looks proper for me): `lsof -i tcp | grep -v iceweasel | awk 'NR > 1 { print $2 }' | xargs -i kill -9 {}`. You could even kill them all directly on one command `lsof -i tcp | grep -v iceweasel | awk 'NR > 1 { print $2 }' | xargs kill -9`

Comment: @Ruslan
it works with NR > 1; I still do not understand because when using echo instead of kill, the first line does not appear; even more, I tried with grep -v COMMAND: It's less elegant than NR > 1 but still allows to ignore first line, and the pb appeared. Anyway the pb is solved thank you very much

Comment: @Cristian
looks very nice with xargs; trying it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @achille, that's weird, because `lsof -i tcp` returns the header unless there are no matching processes, and `lsof` is actually the original executable (`/usr/bin/lsof`), but not an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output of `lsof -i tcp` contains the header, and its `PID` item is eventually passed to the `kill` command (`kill PID`) thus causing the error.

Either use `-t` option for headless output, or ignore the first row with AWK:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print $2 }'
```

where `NR` is the record (line) number.

Note that `kill` only sends `SIGTERM` signal to the process, and the process may merely ignore it. If you want to terminate the process for sure, run `kill` with `-9` (`-KILL`) option (refer to `man 7 signal` for signal codes).

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. For killing all  processes which use tcp except iceweasel:

```
kill $(lsof -c ^iceweasel -a -i tcp -t)
```

Comment: overkilling !!:-D
your syntax does not work but
lsof -c ^icewease -i tcp -t | kill {} does the job just fine

Comment: lsof -c ^icewease -i tcp -t | xargs -i kill {}